# How do you convert epoch time to regular time in Swift 2.0?

Tags: swift, unix, time, type-conversion, epoch

I am retrieving information from an api and I am retrieving a value which holds a time, but the time looks like this, `1469880000` I did some research and realized that this is Epoch time. Now I wonder if you can make a mathmatical equation to convert Epoch to regular time. In there a function or framework in swift to so this? I want to turn this, `1469880000` into this `H:MM --` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alan notes you can use the overloaded method, here's an example.

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1469880000)
```

Then to form it you can do something like the following...

```
let formatString = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'"

func convertTimestampToUTC(inDate:NSDate,formatString:String) -> String{
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = formatString
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    let outDate = formatter.stringFromDate(inDate)
    return outDate
}
```

Then use it like so,

```
let myFormattedDate = convertTimestampToUTC(date, formatString:formatString)
```

I'll update this shortly with some sample output once I get a moment, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:) has a init overload method that works with EPOCH time.

```
import Foundation
let myDate = NSDate.init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1469880000)
print(myDate)
```

Comment: I get an error saying "Expected Declaration", where am I supposed to put this?